# Flash MP3 player with javascript controls

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash, mp3

While the question may seem fairly basic I seem to be at a loss to actually find anything that fits my needs, which are:

- Skinnable (although not 100% required)
- Controllable through javascript (start, stop, change track)
- Event triggers for custom functions (on track finish mainly)
- Actual documentation - rather that 'it can do this, but we wont tell you how'

I've tried many of the free and quite a few demo's of the pay for ones.  Wimpy Wasp seemed to be the closest to what I need but there is an obsession there with using a custom Windows app to set it up which is impossible as the files are provided dynamically by the sites users and it doesn't look like they want you to be able to create the code yourself.

I have no problem with a pay-for solution if it addresses my needs, but free would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JW Flash Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/), to the best of my knowledge, fits that description.

Comment: Meep3D, if you found the answer helpful, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150512/online-mp3-player) I recommend http://opentape.fm/.